# Trying to access kerberized NFS mount gives: 'ERROR: GSS-API: error in gss_acquire_cred()'

Tags: 16.04, nfs, kerberos

I have a kerberized NFS filesystem we're trying to access from an Ubuntu 16.04 client.  The server is RHEL7.  We can mount it successfully (as root):

```
mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 colossal.ipa.localdomain:/export/home /mnt
```

I can run 'df' or 'ls /mnt' as root successfully, but when I try to do the same via a *user* account ('username@localdomain'), rpc.gssd outputs the error:

```
ERROR: GSS-API: error in gss_acquire_cred(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - Can't find client principal username@localdomain in cache collection
```

The full debug output (including KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout) from rpc.gssd is:

> ```
> # rpc.gssd -f -v -v -v -r -r -r
> Warning: rpcsec_gss library does not support setting debug level
> beginning poll
> [...]
> ```

```
handling gssd upcall (/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt0)
handle_gssd_upcall: 'mech=krb5 uid=1388813135 enctypes=18,17,16,23,3,1,2 '
handling krb5 upcall (/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt0)
process_krb5_upcall: service is '<null>'
[28643] 1501554205.58843: Retrieving username@localdomain from FILE:/etc/krb5/user/0/client.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: 2/Key table file '/etc/krb5/user/0/client.keytab' not found
ERROR: GSS-API: error in gss_acquire_cred(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - Can't find client principal username@localdomain in cache collection
getting credentials for client with uid 1388813135 for server colossal.ipa.localdomain
WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 1388813135 for server colossal.ipa.localdomain
doing error downcall
```

'username@localdomain' has a Kerberos TGT in LOCALDOMAIN:

> ```
> $ klist
> Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1388813135:1388813135
> Default principal: username@LOCALDOMAIN
>
> Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
> 01/08/17 12:23:15  01/08/17 22:23:15  krbtgt/LOCALDOMAIN@LOCALDOMAIN
>         renew until 02/08/17 12:23:13
> ```

I'm not clear about why rpc.gssd is trying to read '/etc/krb5/user/0/client.keytab'?  The ccache is in a kernel keyring.

I don't know if it's significant, but the user accounts are obtained through sssd/IPA via an AD trust and have a username of 'username@localdomain' in kerberos realm LOCALDOMAIN (the AD domain).

(I'm able to do this successfully on a RHEL7 NFS client)

Any hints as to what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2017-March/msg00049.html rpc.gssd has no kernel keyring support in Ubuntu 16.04.

In /etc/krb5.conf you have:
  default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

Remove that line and reboot, after that nfs mounts should work.
It worked for me today :-)

Comment: I *thought* this was my solution, it describes what I'm seeing exactly, however, my results are slightly different. After doing this (removing that line from /etc/krb5.conf on my client and restarting the machine), I keep getting this error `ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/shared': Stale file handle` which I assume indicates that this didn't resolve the issue. any suggestions?